# Random selection of a row within a function

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a function so it can be used as a default value for a column in a table. It exists as a procedure at the moment (which cannot be used as a column default) and uses ORDER BY newid() several times. Apparently this cannot be used in a function.

Is there anyway of randomly selecting a row in a user defined function?

Comment: Yes, everytime a new row is inserted in the table the idea is that a new value is generated for the column using a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use this code bellow and adapt it to your needs.

- Sample table:

  ```
  Create Table list(id int identity(0, 1), name varchar(10))
  Go
  Insert into list(name) values('A'), ('B'),('C')
  Go
  ```
- Create a view which only return a newid():

  ```
  Create View viewNewID As Select NEWID() as id
  ```
- Then use it in you function and do whatever you want:

  ```
  Create function randomList()
  Returns int As
  Begin
      Return (Select top 1 id From list Order By (Select id From viewNewId))
  End
  ```
- Sample query returning a random row:

  ```
  select * From List Where id = dbo.randomList()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

A Computed Column is a bad (probably even *very* bad) place to have a random value.

First, if you want this "default" value to remain consistent upon the row being inserted (as opposed to changing every time the row and field are selected), you would need to use the `PERSISTED` keyword so that the computed column is physical stored and not recomputed each time.

Second, while you can usually do either of the following in a computed column, they cannot be used in a `PERSISTED` computed column due to being non-deterministic:

- directly use `NEWID()` and `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()`
- pass `NEWID()` or `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` as a parameter to a User-Defined Function

Third, you could potentially create a SQLCLR function that would be able to call .NET randomization methods, but due to the requirement of a PERSISTED computed column needing to reference only deterministic functions, you would have to mark it incorrectly on purpose as `IsDeterministic = true`, and the effect(s) of this could be bad. At the very least it would allow SQL Server to cache the function output, in which case multiple rows being inserted in the same query (either via an `INSERT...SELECT` construct or an `INSERT INTO VALUES (), (), ()...` construct) could easily have the same "default" value and hence not be random at all.

Fourth, you *could* attempt the "hiding NEWID() in a View so it can be referenced in a UDF" trick as shown in @Julien's answer, but you would need to test that to see if it actually does what you are wanting. You need to particularly test scenarios that insert multiple rows in a single statement since SQL Server does not guarantee that it will run a UDF more than 1 time.

In the end, I think you are FAR better off having this "default" field being a regular field (i.e. not computed) and either determining its value in the Stored Procedure that does the `INSERT`, or determined and set in an `AFTER INSERT` Trigger that updates this "default" field for all new rows.